# How would you fill past a boundary in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fill

By default, the fill tool in Photoshop with contiguous on, would perform an operation such that the specified colour floods until it touches the detected boundaries.

Is there a way of modifying the fill tool, or a series of steps, that would allow the fill colour to flow past the detected boundaries by a specified amount of pixels. Almost like a stroke around the filled colour but with the colour of the stroke corresponding to the fill.

[image]

If such is not possible in Photoshop, could I be directed to software that has such capabilities, preferably a free raster image editor.

Comment: Could make a copy, scale the copy, and remove the border on the copy

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it's possible with just the Fill tool, but there are a couple ways to do this. You could instead use the Magic Wand tool to make a selection then use <kbd>Select > Modify > Expand...</kbd> to add your "stroke", then fill it with <kbd>Edit > Fill...</kbd>

Another way you already said it yourself...it's just a stroke, so you could just add a stroke to the layer. Start by creating a new empty layer, then make sure Contiguous and All Layers are checked in the fill tool options

[image: Fill tool options]

Fill your area, then add a Stroke with the same fill color.

[image: Fill with stroke]

I would prefer the latter method as it would allow me to modify the width of the stroke later on if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it with the fill tool, but maybe you can write a script that combines the select, expand and fill tools to achieve your desired result.